# Choice of attributeGroup

Tags: xml, xsd

## Problem

I must optionally add a set of attributes to the existing *Value* element (see below). This element must not contain more than one set of attributes (see below).

Note: the *unit* attribute is not included in the sets of attributes.

Declaration of the *Value* element:

```
<xs:element name="Value">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="unit" use="required" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Declaration of my two *attributeGroup*s:

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="setOfAttrs1">
    <xs:attribute name= "a" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="b" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="c" type="xs:int" use="required" />
</xs:attributeGroup>
<xs:attributeGroup name="setOfAttrs2">
    <xs:attribute name= "x" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="z" type="xs:int" use="required" />
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

## Correct examples (against schema)

```
<Value unit="m3">i'm correct</value>
<Value unit="m3" x="1" y="1" z="0">i'm correct</value>
<Value unit="m3" a="1" b="1" c="0">i'm correct</value>
```

## Incorrect examples (against schema)

The first misses the `z` attribute; the second contains both sets of attributes.

```
<Value unit="m3" x="1" y="1">i'm incorrect</value>
<Value unit="m3" x="1" y="1" z="0" a="0" b="1" c="0">i'm incorrect</value>
```

## Tried solution

```
<xs:element name="Value">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="PhysicalUnit" use="required" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="setOfAttrs1" />
                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="setOfAttrs2" />
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But this is not a valid XSD:

> **Error** - Line 93, 45: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 93;
>   columnNumber: 45; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of
>   '#AnonType_Value' is invalid.  Element 'choice' is invalid, misplaced,
>   or occurs too often.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Not possible with XSD 1.0 - attributes are not allowed inside `xs:choice`. Either use an XSD 1.1 assertion or put _elements_ into `xs:choice`, and make the attribute set the only difference between the elements - for instance by [deriving two actual types from an abstract type](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200107/msg00038.html).

Comment: @MathiasMüller is correct that this cannot be expressed in XSD 1.0.  See my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29609288/290085) for how to do it in XSD 1.1 using an assertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You cannot express such a constraint in XSD 1.0.**

In XSD 1.1, you can make the attributes be optional and express your complex requiredness constraint via `xs:assert`.  There are three cases you wish to allow:

1. All of a, b, and c but none of x, y, z:

   `@a and @b and @c and not(@x) and not(@y) and not(@z)`
2. None of a, b, and c but all of x, y, z:

   `not(@a) and not(@b) and not(@c) and @x and @y and @z`
3. None of a, b, c, x, y, z:

   `not(@a or @b or @c or @x or @y or @z)`

### XSD 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="Value">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="unit" use="required" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:attributeGroup ref="setOfAttrs1" />
          <xs:attributeGroup ref="setOfAttrs2" />
          <xs:assert test="(@a and @b and @c and not(@x) and not(@y) and not(@z)) 
                            or (not(@a) and not(@b) and not(@c) and @x and @y and @z) 
                            or not(@a or @b or @c or @x or @y or @z)"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="setOfAttrs1">
    <xs:attribute name="a" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="b" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="c" type="xs:int" />
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="setOfAttrs2">
    <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:attribute name="z" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it in XSD 1.1 is to use conditional type assignment. Here you define two types, one of which has attributes a/b/c, the other with attributes x/y/z, and you choose between these two types with a conditional test:

```
<xs:element name="Value" type="ValueType">
  <xs:alternative test="@a" type="ValueTypeWithABC"/> 
  <xs:alternative           type="ValueTypeWithXYZ"/>
</xs:element>
```